# Usercontrol / Control для изменения свойст Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, usercontrol

У меня тех.задача написать UserControl/Control для изменения свойств объекта на который его перетаскивают.

Что-то типа: [Bunifu Ellipse Component  Adds rounded Corners  to forms and controls](https://devtools.bunifu.co.ke/knowledgebase/bunifu-ellipse-component-adds-rounded-corners-to-forms-and-controls/).

Как обычный компонент создать вроде бы ясно, а вот как сделать, чтобы он "навязывал" какие-то свойства тому, на кого-то его перетянули не понятно.

Даже не знаю с чего начать.